# Sublime Text - Highlight Matches without Scrolling

Tags: sublime-text-3

In Sublime Text 3, when searching with Ctrl+F and Highlight Matches enabled, any text typed in will automatically highlight in the editor + you'll automatically scroll to the first instance of it.

Is there anyway to enabled JUST the highlighting part, but require pressing enter to actually scroll to the next result?